# The caller was not authenticated by the service in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

Thanks for your reply but no luck with that code..I am sending you complete config files related to service and application ....Give me any valuable suggession.

Service web.config

application web.config

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see my answer for a suggested configuration setup.

Answer (score 2):

The `wsHttpBinding` has message-level security and by default it uses Windows authentication.  If that is not what you want perhaps you meant to use the `basicHttpBinding`?  This binding is not secured by default.

[`BasicHttpBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.aspx):

> The BasicHttpBinding uses HTTP as the
>   transport for sending SOAP 1.1
>   messages. A service can use this
>   binding to expose endpoints that
>   conform to WS-I BP 1.1, such as those
>   that ASMX clients access. Similarly, a
>   client can use the BasicHttpBinding to
>   communicate with services exposing
>   endpoints that conform to WS-I BP 1.1,
>   such as ASMX Web services or Windows
>   Communication Foundation (WCF)
>   services configured with the
>   BasicHttpBinding.
>
> ***Security is turned off by default***, but
>   can be added setting the
>   BasicHttpSecurityMode to a value other
>   than None in the
>   BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode)
>   constructor. It uses a "Text" message
>   encoding and UTF-8 text encoding by
>   default.

[`WSHttpBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding.aspx):

> The WSHttpBinding is similar to the
>   BasicHttpBinding but provides more Web
>   service features. It uses the HTTP
>   transport and ***provides message
>   security***, as does BasicHttpBinding,
>   but it also provides transactions,
>   reliable messaging, and WS-Addressing,
>   either ***enabled by default*** or available
>   through a single control setting.

**Edit:**  Try this configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint 
            address="http://miplserver02:9050/UserManagementService/UserManagementService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" 
            contract="UMS.IUserManagementService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.can you give the code to replace the wsHttpBinding to BasicHttpBinding.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please post your configuration and I will help you change it.

Comment: Dear Andrew,
I am getting a similar sort of problem while trying to communicate with CRM 2011 Deployment service hosted over SSL. The details of the problem are posted here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426273/caller-was-not-authenticated-by-the-service-error-crm-2011-deployment-wcf-servi
If you could see and suggest a solution? I have posted all the configuration and the associated code. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is probably that authentication is set to anonymous instead of windows.

Check your IIS configuration and web.config for difference between your local machine and the test machine that is failing.

Also are you trying to access IIS on a remote machine while you are logged in as a local user.

Answer (score -2):

Set value of security mode to "None".

```
<security mode="None">
```